# Using Google chart api : chart editor

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am using google chart API and using chart editor in it. I saw few examples was able to add this to my web page, however, the data url is kind of hard coded and I want user to give the data url, I tried a few things but none of it seems to be working.

> HTML code snippet

```
<div id="chartData" class="invisible">
    <div id="chartType">
        <div>Data</div>
        <div>Google Spreadsheet Url (Public)</div>
        <div>
            <input type="url" id="googleURL"/>
         </div>
         <div class="alignCenter">Or</div>
         <div>Enter your own data</div>
     </div>
</div>
<div id="googleChart" class="invisible">
   <input type='button' onclick='openEditor()' value='Open Editor'/>
    <div id='visualization' style="width:80%;height:50%;"> </div>
</div>
```

> Java script Code

```
var wrapper;
function init() {
    wrapper = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        containerId: 'visualization',
        dataSourceUrl: 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AivgZyecjo7adDNOVTZEUWRoU1c2YXhuSXpEcVA1a3c#gid=0',
        chartType: 'LineChart'
    });
    wrapper.draw();
}

function openEditor() {
    closeAllDialogs();
    // Handler for the "Open Editor" button.
    var editor = new google.visualization.ChartEditor();
    google.visualization.events.addListener(editor, 'ok',
        function() {
            wrapper = editor.getChartWrapper();
            wrapper.setDataSourceUrl($('googeUrl').val());
            wrapper.draw(document.getElementById('visualization'));
            openGoogleChartDialog();
        });
    editor.openDialog(wrapper);
}
google.setOnLoadCallback(init);
```

So here I want datasourceurl to be set by $('#googleURL').val();
but it looks like the init function is called at page load by google.setOnLoadCallback(init); 
Is there anyway I can change it.
In this code I have not made any changes as I wanted to give a working code

Answer (score 0):

I guess calling init() not onLoad using google API but on a required event helped